# Set shipping price to zero based on condition in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, free-shipping

I want to make shipping free of cost if a user shops over a certain amount. My question is how to disable or set shipping price to zero when condition is fulfilled?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Set Apply to “Percent of product price discount.
2. Set Apply to Shipping Amount to “Yes.”
3. Set Free Shipping to “For shipment with matching items.”

You will not see any free shipping option in the cart, rather when you select any shipping option, Magento automatically subtracts that shipping cost. Suppose I have two shipping options available to select in cart Table Rate and Flat Rate having costs of 10 and 8 respectively. Now, suppose the user has chosen Flat Rate, now you will see in the total's section that the actual shipping cost that is 8 is now added to the cart total. This is how the rule works.

For more details, go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-free-shipping.html

Comment: Actually, I've made a free shipping bar and I think I don't have to play with configuration of `Free Shipping` module already provided by magento. Or do I need to enable it programmatically  when my condition for free shipping met?